# error MSB3073 exited with code 1 - .dll issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to integrate Cortana to Unity using the following method ( *Simon Jackson* : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1094232/Making-your-game-stand-out-with-Cortana-on-Windows).

Unfortunately I am facing some issues while building the sample on Visual Studio, here is the error message :

```
C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity\Export\WindowsUniversal\CortanaUnity\CortanaUnity.csproj(245,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity\Export\WindowsUniversal\Unity\Tools\AssemblyConverter.exe" -platform=uap -lock="C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity\Export\WindowsUniversal\CortanaUnity\project.lock.json" -bits=32 -path="." -path="..\Players\UAP\x86\Debug" "C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity\Export\WindowsUniversal\CortanaUnity\Assembly-CSharp.dll" "C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity\Export\WindowsUniversal\CortanaUnity\UnityEngine.dll" "C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity\Export\WindowsUniversal\CortanaUnity\UnityEngine.UI.dll" "C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity\Export\WindowsUniversal\CortanaUnity\UnityEngine.Networking.dll"" exited with code 1.
```

It appears that each .dll file of the project products an error. I have read some methods on the forum to correct this problem but none of these works for me. Does anyone has a solution ?

**EDIT**

Here is the whole console error :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CortanaUnity, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
1>  UnityInstallationDir "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor".
1>  UnityWSAPlayerDir "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\MetroSupport".
1>  UnityProjectDir "C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity".
1>  Copying unprocessed assemblies...
1>  Running AssemblyConverter...
1>  System.Exception: AssemblyConverter running on already processed assemblies. There is something wrong with your build.
1>     at Unity.SanityCheckStep.Execute()
1>     at Unity.Step.Execute(OperationContext operationContext, IStepContext previousStepContext)
1>     at Unity.Operation.Execute()
1>     at Unity.Program.Main(String[] args)
1>C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity\Export\WindowsUniversal\CortanaUnity\CortanaUnity.csproj(245,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity\Export\WindowsUniversal\Unity\Tools\AssemblyConverter.exe" -platform=uap -lock="C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity\Export\WindowsUniversal\CortanaUnity\project.lock.json" -bits=32 -path="." -path="..\Players\UAP\x86\Debug" "C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity\Export\WindowsUniversal\CortanaUnity\Assembly-CSharp.dll" "C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity\Export\WindowsUniversal\CortanaUnity\UnityEngine.dll" "C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity\Export\WindowsUniversal\CortanaUnity\UnityEngine.UI.dll" "C:\Users\P1057\Documents\CortanaUnity\Export\WindowsUniversal\CortanaUnity\UnityEngine.Networking.dll"" exited with code 1.
```

And that is the content of the .csproj file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EnableUnmanagedDebugging>false</EnableUnmanagedDebugging>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|ARM'">
    <DeviceId>30F105C9-681E-420b-A277-7C086EAD8A4E</DeviceId>
    <UseEmulator>false</UseEmulator>
    <RemoteDebugMachine>192.168.1.21:4020 (DESKTOP-IJPSV59)</RemoteDebugMachine>
    <RemoteDebugEnabled>true</RemoteDebugEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DeviceId>30F105C9-681E-420b-A277-7C086EAD8A4E</DeviceId>
    <UseEmulator>false</UseEmulator>
    <RemoteDebugMachine>DESKTOP-IJPSV59</RemoteDebugMachine>
    <RemoteDebugEnabled>false</RemoteDebugEnabled>
    <AuthenticationMode>Windows</AuthenticationMode>
    <CreateCleanLayout>false</CreateCleanLayout>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Are you able to provide us more details of the error (similar to as shown at https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/the-command-assemblyconverter-exe-exited-with-code-1.450373/ )?

Comment: @mjwills That is done in edit